# Unlist LAST level of a list in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of list like **ll**:

```
ll <- list(a = list(data.frame(c = 1, d = 2), data.frame(h = 3, j = 4)), b = list(data.frame(c = 5, d = 6), data.frame(h = 7, j = 9)))
```

I want to unnest/unlist the last level of the structure (the interior list). **Note that every list contains the same structure**. I want to obtain **lj**:

```
lj <- list(a = (data.frame(c = 1, d = 2, h = 3, j = 4)), b = data.frame(c = 5, d = 6, h = 7, j = 9))
```

I have tried the following code without any success:

```
lj_not_success <- unlist(ll, recursive = F)
```

However, this code unlists the FIRST level, not the LAST one.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to `cbind` the inner `list` elements instead of `unlist`ing as the expected output is a also a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
ll_new <- lapply(ll, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
```

-checking

```
> identical(lj, ll_new)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is there a way to use your code with "bind_rows" to include the name/value of each list as a variable? The code will work in this fashion ```bind_rows(df, .id = 'grp')```

Comment: @vog did you meant `bind_cols` as in the present context i.e. `purrr::map(ll, bind_cols)` or if it is bind_rows, `purrr::map(ll, ~ bind_rows(.x, .id = 'grp'))`

Comment: Thank you @Akrun !