# Add one variable containing the name of each FINAL list (in a list of lists) in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of lists like **ll**:

```
ll <- list(a = list(data.frame(c = 1, d = 2), data.frame(h = 3, j = 4)), b = list(data.frame(c = 5, d = 6), data.frame(h = 7, j = 9)))
```

I want to add one variable **grp** to each final list. This variable (grp) has to contain the name/value of each list. Therefore the new list of lists may look like **ls**:

```
ls <- list(a = list(data.frame(c = 1, d = 2, grp = 1), data.frame(h = 3, j = 4, grp = 2)), b = list(data.frame(c = 5, d = 6, grp = 1), data.frame(h = 7, j = 9, grp = 2)))
```

**NOTE**: The **grp** may not follow a sequence from 1:n. The approach I look for may be similar to the following one `bind_rows(df, .id = 'grp')`. **The only point is that in this case, I don´t want to row bind** (at least not in this way but in this other [Unlist LAST level of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205748/unlist-last-level-of-a-list-in-r))

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply cycle through the levels with `lapply`

```
setNames( lapply( 1:length(ll), function(x) lapply( 1:length(ll[[x]]), 
  function(y) cbind(ll[[x]][[y]],grp=y ) ) ), names(ll) )
$a
$a[[1]]
  c d grp
1 1 2   1

$a[[2]]
  h j grp
1 3 4   2


$b
$b[[1]]
  c d grp
1 5 6   1

$b[[2]]
  h j grp
1 7 9   2
```

Comment: It may not follow a sequence from 1:n. The approach I look for may be similar to the following one ```bind_rows(df, .id = 'grp')```. The only point is that in this case, I don´t want to row bind (at least not in this way but in this other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205748/unlist-last-level-of-a-list-in-r)

Comment: @vog You may put that in the question. That's critical information for any potential answer.

Comment: Sure! Question edited. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the post it seems the groups are defined iteratively for each nested list. We can use a `seq_along` to create the groups, and apply this on each element of the list `ll`.
**base R**

```
lapply(ll, \(.){
  Map(function(i, n) {n$grp = i ; n}, seq_along(.), .)
})
$a
$a[[1]]
  c d grp
1 1 2   1
$a[[2]]
  h j grp
1 3 4   2
$b
$b[[1]]
  c d grp
1 5 6   1
$b[[2]]
  h j grp
1 7 9   2
```

**purrr**

```
map(ll, ~imap(.x, ~{.x$grp <- .y ; .x}))
```

For similar approaches using purely `lapply`, `mapply` or `purrr::map`, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950144/access-lapply-index-names-inside-fun). In this approach the only difference with the expected result is the class of the vector, an `integer` instead of a `numeric`, see `waldo::compare(ls, ll)`.

Comment: It may not follow a sequence from 1:n. The approach I look for may be similar to the following one ```bind_rows(df, .id = 'grp')```. The only point is that in this case, I don´t want to row bind (at least not in this way but in this other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205748/unlist-last-level-of-a-list-in-r)

Comment: @vog please update your expected output in the original post to reflect your requirements (with edge cases illustrating the problem) - it is unclear to me what the criteria for the `grp` variable are. Can't offer concrete solutions or approaches to *may*. `bind_rows` ... binds rows, which is not shown in the expected output `ls` in the original post.

Comment: The question is edited now. Thank you!